# Ruby on Rails asset precompilation fails on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have this problem that when I try to push to Heroku the error I get is

```
/tmp/build_c6e60f96-b7c3-4985-b3e0-d97e3a8408a8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/tmp/build_c6e60f96-b7c3-4985-b3e0-d97e3a8408a8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/tmp/build_c6e60f96-b7c3-4985-b3e0-d97e3a8408a8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/tmp/build_c6e60f96-b7c3-4985-b3e0-d97e3a8408a8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/tmp/build_c6e60f96-b7c3-4985-b3e0-d97e3a8408a8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
/tmp/build_c6e60f96-b7c3-4985-b3e0-d97e3a8408a8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/tmp/build_c6e60f96-b7c3-4985-b3e0-d97e3a8408a8/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/tmp/build_c6e60f96-b7c3-4985-b3e0-d97e3a8408a8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/tmp/build_c6e60f96-b7c3-4985-b3e0-d97e3a8408a8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
/tmp/build_c6e60f96-b7c3-4985-b3e0-d97e3a8408a8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
/tmp/build_c6e60f96-b7c3-4985-b3e0-d97e3a8408a8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/tmp/build_c6e60f96-b7c3-4985-b3e0-d97e3a8408a8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
/tmp/build_c6e60f96-b7c3-4985-b3e0-d97e3a8408a8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:249:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/tmp/build_c6e60f96-b7c3-4985-b3e0-d97e3a8408a8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in define'
Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
!
!     Precompiling assets failed.
!

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

Answer (score 0):

[precompiling-assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets)

Set `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = flase` in `config/application.rb`

Heroku requires this to be false

Comment: My config.assets.initialize_on_precompile is false

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your using rails 4x, you don't have to change any configuration files for Heroku at all.

All you have to do is add this gem:

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

It will change your configurations to match Heroku's requirements for you. If that doesn't work, I would double check to see if my application.css or application.js was requiring assets that weren't present. Try compiling your assets locally.